# I cant move or delete files with windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo OFF

mkdir output

sort %1 > cadperfiSorted 

//This jar creates a file named OPEACER5

start MAKEOPEACER5.jar cadperfiSorted

del cadperfiSorted

move OPEACER5 output
```

My .bat script basically creates two files.One file called `cadperfiSorted` I want to delete.And the other one `OPEACER5` I want to move to the folder called output.Everything before the calling of those functions ( del and move) worked well.The `del` command doesn't delete the file and the `move` command doesn't move file to the folder especified.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank for your help.I'll give more details to my question.

Comment: Your edit is better. Thanks. You seem to have ignored everything else I wrote (which explains why your code probably isn't working the way you want). Did you check what I mentioned?

Comment: @KenWhite 
I've checked what you mentioned.The parameter wait worked fine.
Thank you , and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Your English is fine. :-) I had no trouble understanding what you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Your jar file most likely has *cadperfisorted* open and *OPEACERS* hasn't been created yet when you try to del and move.

You most likely need to use `start /wait` to give it time to finish before the batch file continues to try to delete and move the files.

```
@echo OFF

mkdir output
sort %1 > cadperfiSorted 

//This jar creates a file named OPEACER5
start /wait MAKEOPEACER5.jar cadperfiSorted

del cadperfiSorted
move OPEACER5 output
```

Comment: Why use START at all?

Comment: @dbenham: Because without it, you can't wait? Because typing `MAKEOPEACERS.jar` at a command prompt or on it's own in a batch file won't execute that jar?

Comment: I don't see how START can launch MAPKEOPEACERS.jar, yet a direct `MAKEOPEACERS.jar cadperfiSorted` not start, and I should think the latter would wait as well. But perhaps there is more to the story that I am not aware of.

Comment: @dbenham: The same way that typing `mydoc.doc` from a command prompt doesn't work (the .doc extension is not executable), but `start mydoc.doc` does (presuming that you have Word installed). `start` will use the extension to find associated applications, while using the filename alone will not go that extra step. The .jar extension is apparently properly associated on the OP's system, as it generates the file that can't be moved.

Comment: @dbenham: You can easily confirm this yourself. Open a command prompt, `cd` to a folder that contains a text file. At the command prompt, type `yourfile.txt`(using the actual filename of your text file), and it does not work. Type `start yourfile.txt`, and Notepad opens with the text file loaded, because Windows looks up the app associated with the .txt extension and launches that app. Also try `start /?` from that prompt.

Comment: OK, thanks. that helps. However, I get the same results with `test.txt` and `start /wait test.txt`, except the start forms waits for notepad to close, while the direct call does not. However, `cmd /c test.txt` launches notepad and waits. So `cmd /c` is an alternative to `start /wait`.

Comment: Um, no. `cmd /c` is different than `start /wait`.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297%28v=ws.10%29.aspx for information. `Start` will use the app associated with an extension that isn't normally executable, and `start /wait` will wait for the application to be finished. Notepad is an exception, because it opens the file, reads and closes it. But you've apparently used a flawed test. At a command prompt, and type the name of your text file (with nothing else) at the prompt, like `C:\Whatever>MyFile.txt` and hit enter; you get an error. Now type `start MyFile.txt`.

Comment: Better yet, do the same replacing the text file with the name of a Word document that's in the folder. Then try a third time, using `start /wait YourWordDoc.doc` and compare the behavior.

Comment: Your description is not as I remember things, and when I test, file.txt and file.doc both work from my command prompt, without START. I know that START /WAIT and CMD /C are not identical, but I'm just saying that in this case, I believe CMD /C is a viable alternative.

Comment: @dbenham: They're not the same. `cmd /c` does something entirely different. (Typing the text file name directly and having it work means you're probably using WIn8 or 10, which handles associations differently from the command line (which is something I just learned - thanks).) `start /wait` will wait for the executable to finish, which in the case of Notepad is immediately (it opens the text file, loads it entirely, and closes the text file, so the text file is done).  `cmd /c` opens a new instance of `cmd.exe` but doesn't wait for the app to finish before executing the next line of the .bat.